# Insert into table the result from stored procedure plus extra columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How to insert a few more columns into the `dbFileListOnly` table along with EXEC query:

```
INSERT INTO admindb..dbfilelistonly (path, col1, col2....)
     @path, EXEC ('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @path + '''')
```

I don't know if it is possible or not. I want to save database name along with `fileListHeader` so that I know while restoring which files belong to a given database.

Comment: try intermediate table

Comment: @IvanStarostin: Yes, that's the last resort I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OPENROWSET` is a tricky way but may comfort you. It allows even to join sp results with other tables.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312%28v=sql.120%29.aspx